# web page does not function with data-confirm and data-method attributes when upgrading from rails 2 to 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Source code:

```
<td class="delete">
<%= link_to 'Destroy', 
  expense, 
  :confirm => 'Are you sure?', 
  :method => :delete, 
  :class => "btnDelete" %></td>
```

Rails 2 generates:

```
<td class="delete">
<a href="/expenses/18051" class="btnDelete" 
onclick="
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { 
    var f = document.createElement('form'); 
    f.style.display = 'none'; 
    this.parentNode.appendChild(f); 
    f.method = 'POST'; 
    f.action = this.href;
    var m = document.createElement('input'); 
    m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
    m.setAttribute('name', '_method'); 
    m.setAttribute('value', 'delete'); 
    f.appendChild(m);
    var s = document.createElement('input'); 
    s.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
    s.setAttribute('name', 'authenticity_token'); 
    s.setAttribute('value','MTAoIigmzVSh39na4GRcpnOQXe1yMQkOYGnzCvZI0Xk='); 
    f.appendChild(s);
    f.submit(); 
  };
  return false;
">Destroy</a></td>
```

Rails 3 generates:

```
<td class="delete">
<a href="/expenses/17732" class="btnDelete" data-confirm="Are you sure?"     
data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
</td>
```

The page does not function the way it did at rails 2 with the generate js and the app does NOT use jquery (yet).  I mention jquery because googling the data-confirm and data-method attributes gets hits that imply jquery is required for them to do anything.

Is there some reference documentation that deals with either any requirements for the data-confirm and data-method attributes to function and/or what rails 3 expects that would enable the code generated by the link-to helper to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since i've created a new rails 3.0 app. Looking at one I have, I think you need to include the rails.js file that is generated when the application was created, and it should take care of things for you.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails" %>
```

Comment: When rails 3 generated the app it didn't give me a rails.js.  However I think you are on the "right track" with the idea that there is a particular js file that rails 3 "expects" to be available.  I'll keep searching offline for both the hypothesized file and any doc discussing it.

Comment: Did you run rails new when you installed rails 3? Here's a gist of the one created for rails 3.0.20: https://gist.github.com/agmcleod/4771210

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: enabling the asset pipeline and coding

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

in a view causes rails to serve the page with its (rail's) copy of the jquery library thus enabling the confirmation message box on the link.  With this level of understanding, what I would like to have seen was 1) documentation on the dependency between the :confirm parameter of the link_to helper on the asset pipeline AND 2) a workaround to allow confirmation even if the asset pipeline is disabled.